# How to filter the data in shiny using select input?

Tags: r, shiny

I wanted to filter the district names in two of the data sets based on the drop-down selection and map them using plots. I get the following error message.

> Error : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. i Input `..1` is
> `district == input$district`. x Can't access reactive value 'district'
> outside of reactive consumer. i Do you need to wrap inside reactive()
> or observe()?

```
library(shiny)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(tidyverse)
library(osrm)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(readxl)

dst = c('A',
            'B',
            'C')

raw1 <- read_xlsx("raw_map.xlsx")
clean1 <- read_xlsx("clean_map.xlsx")

ui <- fluidPage(

   
    titlePanel("District data viz"),

    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("district",
                         "Name of the dst:",
                         choices = dst),
        ),

        
        mainPanel(
          fluidRow(12,leafletOutput("raw")),
          fluidRow(12,leafletOutput("clean")),
           
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  raw <- dplyr::filter(raw1, district == input$district)
  clean <- dplyr::filter(clean1, district == input$district)
  output$raw <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = raw) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      
      addMarkers(lng = raw$lon, lat = raw$lat,
                 label = raw$CHE_Village,
                 popup = raw$CHE_Name,
                 labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) 
  })
  output$clean <- renderLeaflet({
    
      leaflet(data = clean) %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        
        addMarkers(lng = clean$lon, lat = clean$lat,
                   label = clean$CHE_Village,
                   popup = clean$CHE_Name,
                   labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) 
  })
    

    
        
        

        
}    


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try declaring raw and clean as reactive objects (and update their names as raw() and clean() when you use them).

Comment: ... or put them inside the `renderLeaflet`.